# Intervention Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker, timepicker

I am trying to integrate [material-ui timepicker](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-time-picker).

Here is the code

```
handleChange(time) {
  console.log(time)
}

<TimeInput
  mode='12h'
  value={new Date(moment(fromTime, 'hh:mm a'))}
  onChange={(time) => this.handleChange(time)}
/>
```

But when I try to change the time I got this warning

```
[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use css property on your component container div touch-action: none

```
.container {
    touch-action: none;
}
```